# Left:calc() not working in safari

Tags: css, safari

I want to make a div exact center of screen even while re-sizing it. I tried `left:calc(55% - <width in px>);` but it does not work in Safari.

Comment: What Safari version you tested it on?

Comment: Why 55%? `calc` is prefixed in Safari 6.0 and not supported before that: http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: And why calc? `left: 50%;` `margin-left: -{width in px};`

Comment: .MyDiv
{
    color:#555;
    border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    font-size:12px;
  position:fixed;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
  height:20px;
  width:80%;
  max-width:470px;
top:40%; 
left:-webkit-calc(55% - 335px);

  display:none;
  z-index:99999;
  background-color:#fff;  
    } ...... I want to repair it and make it work in safari 5.x.x

Comment: Calc is not supported in Safari 5: Polyfill - https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc

Comment: See Polyfill - https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc

Comment: OK. Thanks. I think I must update Safari.

Comment: Thanks to all for reply.